# Electron can't find file when path is correct

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, electron

I am requiring a JavaScript file which is located within my external resources within built electron package.

```
let rPath = eval(require(path.resolve(__dirname + `/../src/raffles/boltRaffle0${_this.rPassID}.js`)));
```

When I run the application I get:

> components sync:2 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module
>   'C:\Users\James\AppData\Local\Programs\bolt-beta\resources\src\raffles\boltRaffle04.js'
>       at n (webpack:/src/components sync:2)
>       at o.**webpack_require** (webpack:/src/components/Main.vue:686)
>       at passRaffle (webpack:/src/components/Main.vue?c5be:1)
>       at apply (webpack:/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:2027)
>       at HTMLDivElement.apply (webpack:/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm.js:1826)

I'm not sure why it can't find the file as it is there. Furthermore if I run

```
let rPath = eval(require(path.resolve(__dirname + `/../src/raffles/boltRaffle0${_this.rPassID}.js`)));
```

within the console, while the app is running it finds the file.

I'm not sure if it has anything to do with Webpack? Just in case here my webpack.config.js

```
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.vue$/,
            use: 'vue-loader'
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        new VueLoaderPlugin(),
        new browserPlugin({
            openOptions: {
                app: [
                    'chrome',
                    //'--incognito',
                    '--disable-web-security', // to enable CORS
                    '--user-data-dir=' + path.resolve(chromeUserDataDir) // to let Chrome create and store here developers plugins, settings, etc.
                ]
            }
        })
    ]

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File path acting strange](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52957458/file-path-acting-strange)

Comment: @pergy Deleted previous related questions. Any idea why it can't find the file even though the path is correct?